# Why does image gets aligned at uppermost top but text not?

Tags: html, css

In the following example i'm examining the behavior of the `vertical-align` property. And one oddity i have noticed is that when assigning the top value on a element inside the line box the image gets aligned at the absolute top but the text inside the `<span>` element doesn't. Why is this?

```css
 .box {
           font-size: 64px;
           line-height: 100px;
        }
        
        span {
            font-size: 16px;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        
        img {
            vertical-align: top;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="box">ppp
        <span>hello</span>
        <img src="star.png"/>
    </div>
```

I also have another question regarding terminology, i've seen both the terms `line` and `line-box` used together such as in this section of the [CSS specification:](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting)

```
The rectangular area that contains the boxes that form a line is called a line box.
```

But what exactly is a line and how does it differ from a line-box?

Comment: span is aligned on top, but it has a line-height of 100px, so it's (100-16)/2 px from top (line-height minus font size divided by 2)

Comment: @s_frix Intersting, so line-box is only per line of text, not the entire container with ALL lines of texts?